# How to redirect output of curl to multiple files?

Tags: linux, automation, curl, ansible

```
curl http://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/keystone/plain/httpd/keystone.py?h=stable/kilo \ | tee /var/www/cgi-bin/keystone/main /var/www/cgi-bin/keystone/admin
```

How redirect output of a command to files using Ansible?

For now I am using `shell` module of Ansible:

```
shell: curl http://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/keystone/plain/httpd/keystone.py?h=stable/kilo \ | tee /var/www/cgi-bin/keystone/main /var/www/cgi-bin/keystone/admin
```

Are there any other ways for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `get_url` module:

```
- get_url: url=http://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/keystone/plain/httpd/keystone.py?h=stable/kilo dest={{ item }}
  with_items:
    - /var/www/cgi-bin/keystone/main
    - /var/www/cgi-bin/keystone/admin
```

Set `force=true` to overwrite the file if the file exists on the target host(s).

`ansible-doc get_url` for more details.